# Dynamically load class by name in Zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, autoload

I am currently trying to get an instance of a class by its name. I have a controller and in this controller i would like to get an instance of a class by its **classname**. I know that the class will be in the namespace **MyModule\Entity**.

What is the best way to dynamically create an instance of a class with Zend 2 ?

```php
namespace MyModule\Controller;

class MyController extends AbstractActionController {

public function indexAction() {
    $className = "myclass"; // File myclass.php
    $class = ??? // create instance by $className
    $class->process();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ZF1 I would do

```
$class = new MyModule_Entity_Classname();
```

I don't know if this changed in ZF2.

Comment: This still works in ZF2. But i am not sure if this is the best way to achieve this !?

Comment: You can also put a "use MyModule\Entity\Classname as Classname;" at the beginning of your controller and then just do $class = new Classname();

Comment: But that would be a bit too much, due to the fact if i will have 100 or more differnt classes that i have to load, depending on the class name. Thats why i want to load the class dynamicaly.

Comment: waow that's a lot ! I think `$classname = "MyModule\Entity\Classname"; $class = new $classname;` works if that was your first question

Answer (score 0):

If you use composer and it's configured properly you can use:

```
$class = new $className;
```

but `$className` should be full name of class, e.g. `\MyModule\MyClass`